# How to show some posts options, only for the creator of the post in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm getting the error "undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass", but my code looks good to me. I checked from the Rails console, and the posts do have the`user_id` field and it works as expected.

This is my posts model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  body       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :integer
#

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :body, presence: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my `create` action in my posts controller:

```
def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.user = current_user
        if @post.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
```

This is the portion of my view where I try to "moderate" who has access to the edit and delete:

```
<% if signed_in? && @post.user == current_user %>

    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this post?"} %>
<%end%>
```

Here is the error trace:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-02-06 15:48:00 -0500
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass):
     9:                     <div class="post-container hyphenate">
    10:                         <%= post.body %>
    11: 
    12:                         <% if signed_in? && @post.user == current_user %>
    13: 
    14:                             <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
    15:                             <%= link_to "Delete", post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this post?"} %>
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb__995985056227498542_70346416865540'
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__995985056227498542_70346416865540'
```

Comment: Can you include the error stacktrace, and the relevant code it references?

Comment: @Jon, just added it, thanks.

Comment: Looks like `@post` is not set.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't USE ALL CAPS, because you're yelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<% if signed_in? && @post.user == current_user %>
```

to

```
<% if signed_in? && post.user == current_user %>
```

There is no `@post` on the `index` page.

Comment: Dammit, I had to get my pizza out of the oven and you nipped in there before me :p

Comment: Enjoy your meal, @Jon